# Redireccion ante una URL invalida

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

Estoy necesitando que ante una URL invalida por ejem http:localhost:8080/saddsadas

Me redireccione al index o a la pantalla de login dependiendo si estoy logeado o no.

Lo que hice fue hacer lo siguiente:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Esta parte es para un timeout por otra cosa
        if (Response.RedirectLocation != null && Response.RedirectLocation != "/Home/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fTimeoutRedirect")
        {
            if ((Response.StatusCode == 302) && Response.RedirectLocation.Contains("?ReturnUrl=%2fHome"))
            {
                string newRedirect = "/Home/TimeoutRedirect";
                Response.RedirectLocation = newRedirect;
            }
        }

        if (Response.StatusCode == 404 && !IsWebApiRequest())
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
                Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home"));
            }
            else
            {
                var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
                Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Action("Login", "Home"));
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsWebApiRequest()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith("~/api");
    }
```

Corriendolo en Visual Studio funciona correctamente pero al montarlo en IIS en mi servidor de desarrollo no redirecciona sino que tira error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saben porque pasa esto o otra forma de hacerlo?

Solucion:

Genere un ErrorController

```
public class ErrorController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult NotFoundLogin()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }

    public ActionResult NotFoundIndex()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Preferi cambiar a usar Application_Error y hacer la redireccion de la siguiente manera:

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();

        // Process 404 HTTP errors
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        if (httpException != null && httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404 && !IsWebApiRequest())
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

            // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
            IController controller = new ErrorController();
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotFoundIndex");
            }
            else
            {
                routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotFoundLogin");
            }

            var requestContext = new RequestContext(
            new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
            controller.Execute(requestContext);
        }
    }
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas definir codigo para redireccionar ante un error 404, podrias aplicar esto por configuracion

[Default redirect for Error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483849/default-redirect-for-error-404)

[ASP.NET MVC 404 Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling)

entonces

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" >
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/Index" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

en tu caso ante este error podrias redireccionar a la pagina principal

Si configuras la autenticacion de asp.net y no lo esta previamente acreditada se redireciona a la pagina de login de forma automatica, no necesitas hacer nada especial

Comment: Buenas Leandro, te comento antes de implementar la redireccion la idea era que redireccione a una pagina de error.cshtml, intente con customErrors y httperrors y ninguno funcionaba asi que evite usar customerrors esta vez. Ya lo solucione ahora sumo la solucion aunque coincido que es mucho mas limpio de la manera que me planteas.